# linear and relative layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity"
      android:orientation="vertical"  >

      <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />

     <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

       <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="DEALS IN:-"
       android:padding="10dp"/>

      </LinearLayout>
     
      </RelativeLayout>
```

in relative layout when i set height and weight as match_parent my text slides to the bottom of the design panel and is not visible, why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify how a view is positioned within a `RelativeLayout`.
You can check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative):

> The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent `RelativeLayout` area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).

For example use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="DEALS IN:-"
         android:padding="10dp"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in your layout there is another issue:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <TextView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` has `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and in this way it fills the parent view and the `TextView` is outside the `RelativeLayout`.

[image]

Comment: are you suggesting that here RelativeLayout is a child of LinearLayout and therefore that is the problem i was not getting?

Comment: @mittal_sahil The RelativeLayout is a child of a LinearLayout, but it is not a problem (it depends by what you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here are mistakes with tags.

This should help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="DEALS IN:-" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I suggest you use constraint layout where you have more possibilities.